# How to find first intersection of a ray with moving circles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry

I have been struggling with a problem for a while and so far have not found any solution better then the naive one:

N circles are given that are moving according to a linear law. For each of the circles we have its initial (at moment 0.0) radius, initial coordinates and its radius and coordinates at moment 1.0 (end moment). We also have k rays given with coordinates of their origin and a vector along the ray. Each ray only exists at a given moment t<sub>k</sub>. I need to be able to find the first intersection of a ray with any of the circles. The expected number of k is quite large (millions or billions) as well as the expected number of circles (thousands). I need solution faster then checking all rays against all circles.

I have been searching round the internet for some time but I have found no good solution approach. Even an idea for the easier problem of the circles not moving will be appreciated.

I have the feeling that a kd-tree should be appropriate for the static case and maybe a kinetic kd-tree will solve the harder one. Still I cannot figure out how to use kd-tree even for the easier one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this as static case in 3D with time as additional coordinate. Circle with path became frustum and ray is in a plane time=t<sub>k</sub>. If frustums are not positioned too dense than binary space partitioning (k-d tree, ...) can help.

To find all partitions crossed by ray first find partition where is origin and than traverse (in tree) by partition neighbour in ray direction. It depends on partitioning method used. It is linear in number of partitions crossed by ray.

**Update:** It is idea to put frustum in each partition it is touching. One frustum will be in more partitions.

This is an example in 1 dimension plus time. Everything is same, circles have starting and ending point and starting and ending radius.

```
1  |    E   /
   |   .   /
   |   .  / 
   |  .  /
   |  . /
0  | S /
t/X
```

Partitioning in X direction:

```
   |    E : /
   |   .  :/
   |   .  : 
   |  .  /:
   |  . / :
   | S /  :
          X
```

This trapezoid will go in both partitions.

Partitioning in time direction:

```
   |    E : /
   |   .  :/
   |   .  : 
t-------------------
   |  . / :
   | S /  :
          X
```

Trapezoid from X left partition will go in both time partitions, while in X right partition it will go only in upper partition.

To implement it it is needed to calculate is there an intersection between line and axis plane on some plane part and if there is no intersection on which side of a plane is a line. Calculation is same in 2D case, or even in higher dimensions.

Comment: I considered such an approach but the bad thing in it is that it does not improve the worst case complexity.

Comment: Do you mean worst case because of dense frustums (overlapping) or number of partitions checked?

Comment: Number of partitions checks. I imagine you put only the centers of the circles in the kd-tree and then their radiuses could be chosen in such a way that no actual optimization is achieved.

Comment: Put whole frustums in k-d tree and split also on time coordinate.

Comment: Could you explain in more details how do you put the frustrums in a kd-tree? Also I have a problem with splitting over time - even a tiny difference in this coordinate makes the distance infinite so you can not use regular euclid distance, right?

Comment: Put frustum in each partition it is touching. Look at time as other coordinates, you can even rename it as Z :-) I will post some images to describe later.

Comment: I am very sorry but I still can not understand your idea. It seems to me you will create the kd-tree according to the centers in 3d space and then put fustrums in all partitions they belong to. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. That is idea for space partitioning of 'larger objects', in this case frustums. Since we need to check each partition, that have some frustum points, for possible intersection.

Comment: The idea is pretty much what you described - you need to consider circles in 3d space adding time as additional coordinate for the time. To handle the fact that the circles are moving you need to  [kinetize](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.103.7866%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=MGgVT_eNEpGAtQbYmo0-&usg=AFQjCNEpPBqOPbd5VCtLU34xe11D3rIxJA&sig2=Yo___gOvbWaFBFV8IRYfCw) your kd-tree. Please add these additions to you comment. Anyways I accept it and +1 it.

Answer (score 0):

(Thinking out loud) You might want to use an octree or multi-resolution grid with Bresenham's algorithm to quickly eliminate a lot of checks?

Comment: How does bresenham help here?

Comment: Bresenham would allow you to determine which items of your grid each ray passes through (grid items = pixels in this case)

Comment: Hmm I don't think this idea will help as the length of the ray may be really big and also there is no upper or lower limit to the radius of a sphere so it is kind of hard to choose a size of the grid.

Comment: If you have no prior data about your problem, it's doubtful that you will be able to do better than brute force...